# finding file extension given root name of fie

Tags: bash, shell, file-extension

Hi i have a 2 bash scripts which I'm trying to get to work together. The first script is given a a name of a file along with the directory the file is located within like such:

```
 example_file
 /var/www/some_directory
```

The second script is used to do processing on the file in question based on the file type ie. if example_file.txt the script does one thing and if it is example_file.mkv something else entirely. 
I am looking for a way to have the second script automatically determine the file extension type based on solely the name of the filename and directory its located within (ie. look in /var/www/some_directory for example_file and properly determine extension of file) so that given

```
  example_file
```

the script returns one of

```
  example_file.txt  OR example_file.mkv  OR example_file. mp3 etc etc
```

pleas note that the directory only contains a few files and one and only one with name example_file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
basename $(ls /var/www/some_directory/example_file.*)
```

Comment: this does work, i will accept answer as soon as stackoverflow alows me to thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly:
  - you have a file without extension
  - you want your script to output its name adding the proper extension?

If so : `man file` (on a unix system, `file` determines the content of the file using what's called "magic", wich is the first few bytes of the file, and outputs different description according to what the magic bytes tells it)

Comment: thanks oliver the question has beeen answered by first post I am aware of file though I'm not authenticating (this is done by third-party) Im just wishing to convert files of certain types, I appreciate the help non the less

Answer (score 0):

Grab the filename from a listing and then action on it using a switch-statement:

```
#! /bin/bash

dir="/var/www/some_directory"
file_prefix="example_file"

filename=$(ls -1 "$dir" | grep "^$file_prefix")
case "$filename" in
    *.txt)
        # do txt stuff
        ;;
    *.mp3)
        # do mp3 stuff
        ;;
    *)
        echo unrecognized
        ;;
esac
```